# Delete line if the xpath if xpath can't be found in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a python script using selenium that checks a list of urls and does actions there.

Now I want if the xpath can't be found it removes that specific line from my txt file. How can I do this?

**This is my code**

```
def post(status):
        with open("fbgroepen.txt") as listOfGroups:
            for group in listOfGroups:
                driver.get(group)
                time.sleep(5)
                try:
                    if status:
                        #try posting
                        try:
                            postClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"))).click()
                            #typ bericht
                            post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"))).send_keys(message)
                            #click op post
                            post_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div"))).click()
                            time.sleep(2)
                            #wacht tot gepost
                            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span")))

                        #continue to next url if xpath is'nt found
                        except:
                            continue
                    else:
                        continue
                except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
                    continue
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if understood corretly, but if you assume that:

```
#continue to next url if xpath is'nt found
except:
    continue
```

this part catches exception that represents the situation where xpath is not found (imo the Exception is too broad but lets leave it for now) You could open another file, e.g.

```
open("fbgroepen.tmp")
```

and write to it every line that has been found and at the end of the script something like that:

```
import shutil
```

def post(status):

```
tmp_file = open("fbgroepen.tmp", "w")

with open("fbgroepen.txt") as listOfGroups:
    for group in listOfGroups:
        driver.get(group)
        time.sleep(5)
        try:
            if status:
                #try posting
                try:
                    postClick = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span"))).click()
                    #typ bericht
                    post_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div"))).send_keys(message)
                    #click op post
                    post_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div"))).click()
                    time.sleep(2)
                    #wacht tot gepost
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span")))
                    
                    tmp_file.write(group)
                    
                #continue to next url if xpath is'nt found
                except:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            continue 
            
tmp_file.close()
shutil.copyfile("fbgroepen.tmp", "fbgroepen.txt")
```

Comment: but how can we automatic delete the url that doesnt have the xpaths? @PiWo

Comment: @Teun I don't know where or how the url is stored - you wrote: "Now I want if the xpath can't be found it removes that specific line from my txt file." so i assume it's in the file "fbgroepen.txt". In the proposed solution this script will twor Excelption before writing to the temp file (except: continue)